# scala 2.10 - Stringbuilder constructor not working

Tags: scala

I came across this issue when I was trying to form strings build with Integers. I used scala's Stringbuilder and see this weird behavior.

```
println(new StringBuilder(1).append(2).append(3))
>23
println(new StringBuilder(1.toString()).append(2).append(3))
>123
```

Am I doing something wrong or just implicit conversion not taking place in constructor argument and ignores it silently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [constructor](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src%2Flibrary%2Fscala%2Fcollection%2Fmutable%2FStringBuilder.scala#L62) takes an `Int` for starting capacity, which is why you don't see it as output in your string:

```
def this(capacity: Int) = this(capacity, "")
```

Comment: @nir, generally I would recommend not using the constructor to initialize the `StringBuilder`, only use `append`, and don't feel stupid, it happens to all of us...

Comment: @Noah Why not? Once you know what they mean, just use them accordingly

Comment: @JeanLogeart I would agree with you except the overloaded constructor is a bit of a non-starter for me. Overloaded constructors seem to just confuse things, like in this question here.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 2 different constructors:

1. [`StringBuilder(int capacity)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder-int-): Constructs a string builder with no characters in it and an initial capacity specified by the capacity argument.
2. [`StringBuilder(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder-java.lang.String-): Constructs a string builder initialized to the contents of the specified string.

So `new StringBuilder(1)` returns an **empty** new `StringBuilder` of initial capacity `1`.